# How can I use variables inside the key of a NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to insert a variable in the key of a `NSUserDefault`?

for example:

```
NSUserDefault.setInteger(10, forKey: "number /(var)")
```

I just tried a random syntax, just to make you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats possible:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(10, forKey: "number \(temp)")
```

here `"number \(temp)"` is a complete string.

You can try this way to conform:

```
let temp = 10
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(10, forKey: "number \(temp)")
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("number \(temp)"))
```

Which will print `Optional(10)`